# how to remove circle form export to pdf line chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, export-to-pdf

i am exporting line chart to PDF. it exported successfully but the issue is it will display circles on line on export to PDF File. while on chart i removed that circles using  "#Chart circle{display: none !important;}" CSS Code. now i also need to remove that circle from export to PDF as well

Comment: provide us with some code?

Comment: Please Refer this  http://dojo.telerik.com/AKelA/15.      i also need to combine this both the chart into 1 PDF is it possible

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the markers via CSS, use the chart options

http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-series.markers.visible

```
  series: [{
            type: "line",
            field: "value",
            markers: {
                visible: false
            }

        }],
```

> Updated **[DOJO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/anAqu)**

Comment: Thank you, ezanker  , now i need to export both the chart in on1 pdf is it doable>

Comment: @VMS, yes. Here is an updated DOJO:  http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/anAqu  and here is the demo from telerik: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pdf-export/index